# where can I find manual for craft forms

Tags: form

there is tool `forms`(/craft/app/templates/_includes/). But I cannot find usage manual, ex. options for `forms.select` etc. Where is it, guys? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

At this time, there is no manual for it.

It's an incredibly useful chunk of code, but it's buried pretty deep in the system. I think the belief is that "if you're capable of finding it, you're capable of backwards-engineering it."

I'd actually suggest looking to other parts of Craft (and other plugins) to gain a better understanding of some real-world applications and examples.

Answer (score 0):

That is not answer just example of one of the tag

```
{{ forms.select({
        label: "Default Status"|t,
        options: { "optval1": "Text1", "optval2": "Text2" },
        id: 'defaultStatus',
        name: 'defaultStatus',
        value: settings.defaultStatus,
        errors: settings.getErrors('defaultStatus')
    }) 
}}
```

I hope will be useful for someone

Comment: Dear user, I think this is not very useful as an answer. But you can edit your question and make your question more useful with this snippet of code, thanks!